# Value from 1st class not in 2nd class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two classes, Step1 and Step2. Step1 contains a textfield called wrp. When the user enters a number in wrp in Step1, I would like to be able to work with it in Step2. Here is what I have tried (this is code in Step2):

```
int AdditionalDays;

Step1ViewController *wrp1 = [Step1ViewController new];
UITextField *wrp = [wrp1 wrp];
AdditionalDays = [wrp.text intValue];

TotalTotal.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", AdditionalDays];
```

The app does not throw an error message, but the user-entered number in wrp in Step1 is disregarded in Step2. I don't know why it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason is that you are creating a new instance of Step1ViewController with that "new" statement. This is not the same instance as the one where you are changing the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `Step1ViewController *wrp1 = [Step1ViewController new];` you are creating a new instance of `Step1ViewController`. What you need to to is get a reference to the original Step1ViewController the user entered the text in.

To do this, you would probably create a property in your Step2ViewController where you can pass in either the Step1ViewController, or even better, the value the user entered.

So in your Step2ViewController class header, add a property like this:

```
@property (assign) int additionalDays;
```

Then, when you create the Step2ViewController to display it on screen, you set this property to the value the user entered, like this:

```
Step2ViewController *controller  = [Step2ViewController new];
controller.additionalDays = [wrp.text intValue];
// push the controller on a UINavigationController or something
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you create a new Step1ViewController

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is happening is that in Step2 you have said:

```
Step1ViewController *wrp1 = [Step1ViewController new];
UITextField *wrp = [wrp1 wrp];
```

Unfortunately this isn't doing what you want it to do. Your app doesn't know what you're trying to do and so what the code is actually doing is "Please create a brand new Step1 and also create a brand new TextField, then give me the value of this brand new empty TextField".

Instead of being inside Step2 and working backwards to get the TextField, try to be inside Step1 and pass the value to Step2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I go about doing this? How do I stay in Step1 and pass the value to Step2? (Sorry, I am new to objective-c, and so far I have only worked with single-view applications).

Comment: It depends on how you are transitioning and how you might go about getting a reference to Step2. Ahti has provided one example.